# Javascript script keeps running even when i render another page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a page on my website that uses this song player [wikplayer](https://www.wikplayer.com/), let's call it the index page. the page has an anchor tag with an href to '/calm' route which renders 'calm.ejs'. The 'calm.ejs' page does not have the song player yet the player stays on it which is very weird (but when I go to the route using the browser the player is not there)

This is the song player code:

```html
    <script id="ds" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.wikplayer.com/code.js" 
    data-config="{'skin':'skins/wikfull/plainBlack/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'showcomment':false,'marqueetexton':true,'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':true,'playlist':[{'title':'hey%20there%20delilah','url':'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPoaT6WXUV_M'},{'title':'im%20yours','url':'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DRILP53OR63k'}, {'title':'we%20are%20young','url':'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DKXJNoC6CuYE'}]}" >
    </script>
```

I am thinking that maybe the reason is that the script keeps running in the background which makes it stay on the next page. How do I terminate it once the index page is closed? or how do I mimic the get request that the browser does instead of the one that the anchor tag triggers?

Comment: Can you post your render code? The problem is that you are rendering a new page and not redirecting.

Comment: @MuhandJumah it is just a simple code that renders the 'calm.ejs' page `app.get('/calm',  function(req, res){
 

res.render("calm.ejs")

})`

Comment: Got it, I am almost certain it is because you are rendering, try `redirect`. Although I am sure it is not a best practice. Unfortunately, I am not sure what to do either, this is not my line of expertise. I hope someone would help you solve your problem. Good luck!